# CSS not loading on web-server

Tags: javascript, css, nginx, server, semantic-ui

I am building a website on a nginx server, and want to use the semantic-ui template. I am using node.js with express, but the CSS just won't load... The console says it can't locate the files, but when i run the code on my local machine, it works fine. Has anyone encountered this before?

Heres my code:

app.js

```
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var path        = require('path');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('/public'));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));


require('./routes/routes')(app);

app.listen(8000, function () {
    console.log('server running on port 8000')
});
```

routes/routes.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('construction.ejs');
    });
};
```

construction.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My website</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui container raised very padded text segment">
        <h1>WELCOME!!</h1>
        <p>This page is still under construction...</p>
        <p>Check back in a few weeks ;-)</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your nginx config? What do the nginx logs say? What do the express logs say?

Comment: How do you connect node.js with nginx?

Comment: thanks for the replies!I reset my server and now it seems to be working... i tried to configure nginx to run on https, could that cause an issue?